# how to escape double quotes in jenkins pipeline

Tags: bash, jenkins, groovy, terraform

I have this Jenkins pipeline:

```
sh """ docker container run \
                        --name ssapi-eks-deployer \
                        -e BRANCH=delete\
                        -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID \
                        -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_KEY \
                        -e ACTION=${params.ACTION} \
                        -e API_VERSION=${params.API_VERSION} \
                        http://docker.image """
```

This docker image run a script which has this choice:

```
if [[ $ACTION == "DEPLOY" ]]; then
        echo "=========Deploying EKS ========="
        terraform apply -auto-approve -var-file=project.tfvars -var='apiversion={"$ENV"="$API_VERSION"}'
```

The problem is that the result of this script is this:

```
terraform apply -auto-approve -var-file=project.tfvars -var='apiversion={pre=1.0}'
```

And the **expected result** is this:

```
terraform apply -auto-approve -var-file=project.tfvars -var='apiversion={"pre"="1.0"}'
```

I tried to escape with "" and using double double quotes, with no success.. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Does a backslash work?  (`-var='apiversion={\"$ENV\"=\"$API_VERSION\"}'`)

Comment: nope.. I get the command literally with $ENV and $API_VERSION, not the values of the vars @JeffScottBrown

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape it using `\`:
Example:

```
 bat "terraform apply -auto-approve -var-file=project.tfvars -var='apiversion= {\"${ENV}\"= \"${API_VERSION}\"} ' "
```

Comment: If I scape like this, I get the $env and $api_version literally and I need to Jenkins fill this vars..@Altaf

Comment: @HumbertoLantero I did this with `` bat echo `` command and variable got filled.Are you invoking directly?